# Clear parts of a page before the PHP code

Tags: php

**Hypothetical Question**

I'm working on a thing, that is difficult to explain, but take a page PHP file like this

```
<html>
    ...content...
</html>

<?php 
    code();
?>
```

Is there a way for the code function to cause the contents of the html not to render. This is the goal. Keep in mind, I specifically don't want to place code at the head, like you normally would. Ultimately, I am trying to discount the procedural loading, I suppose.

Comment: Does it really have to be php? Don't you want it to be jquery/js?

Comment: @user Unfortunately yes. It is apart of a test/challenge thing, and I'd like to avoid putting anything at the top of the file, above the HTML. I am aware that this may not be possible, which is my thinking, somewhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way for the code function to cause the contests of the html not to render

```
<html>
    ...content...
</html>
```

Nope, you have lost all those rights after this point. So there is no Way following PHP code can stop it now. Unless you use **[auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)** or any webserver related hacks to process any other PHP code first which uses output buffering which stops any output being sent to the browser in the first place. But if in any case its ever sent you can't stop it after that.

```
<?php 
    code();
?>
```

Comment: ... and also, i think at this point php (of which works at the backend) has no more power over the frontend.

Comment: Actually... there is a way. Getting a parse error inside the php block. But I don't think that is desired

Comment: Nope, even that parse error can not bring back any output that was sent to the client before that parse error occurred